# In Pokemon Go, I never got an egg. Is egg not enabled in USA?

Tags: pokemon-go

I am already at level 10, but I never got any egg at PokeStop.  Every time, I saw a Pokemon and captured it, but never getting an egg and no need to use the egg incubator.

But I did get some "Lucky Eggs" which will double my XP for the next 30 minutes... I don't use the incubator for these, do I?

Comment: eggs can be found in a separate tab on the Pokemon page and not in your inventory, and they have a limit of 9. Are you sure you don't have any of them?

Comment: Just to be sure, you know that the method for getting eggs is different than the method for getting Pokemon, right? You have to click on the Pokestop, then spin the thing in the center, and click the items that come out. Some of them should be eggs, sometimes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The lucky egg is just an item, and does not need to be used in an incubator.

As for eggs themselves, it seems unlikely that you are simply unlucky enough to never get an Egg. From the Pokemon tab, if you swipe to the left or click "Eggs" at the top, you will see your egg inventory. If you have earned any without knowing it, they will appear here.